# Angular-ui bootstrap datepicker won't openup twice

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular-ui bootstrap datepicker component. on one view where I have two date fields, the datepicker opens up and after closed it opens up again when clicked fine.

On another page, after once opened and closed, the datepicker does not open up anymore.

Surely I'm missing something here, but I gave up after hours of trying to find it.

Can you help ?

the HTML section of the datepicker looks as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="input-sm-7" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" is-open="opened"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-model="singleDate"
                               close-text="Close" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i
                                class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

The JS code in the controller looks like this:

```
            $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1
        };

        $scope.open = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();
            $event.stopPropagation();

            $scope.opened = true;
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue and there is a hack for it. Try this.

```
$scope.datePicker = {};
$scope.open = function ($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();
  $scope.datePicker.opened = true;
};
```

Change in the Html

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="input-sm-7" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" is-open="datePicker.opened"
                               datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-model="singleDate"
                               close-text="Close" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i
                                class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: what cause this problem ?